# Only finitely many fundamental groups in $M(n,k,v,D)$?  

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, at.algebraic-topology

Let $M(n,k,v,D)$ denote the class of compact manifolds with $Ric \ge \left( {n - 1} \right)k,vol \ge v,diam \le D$.In 1990,M.Anderson proved that "There are only finitely many fundamental groups among the manifolds in $M(n,k,v,D)$ for fixed n,k,v,D".(Peter Peterson "Riemannian geometry",page 277).The beginning of the proof is "Choose generators $\{ {\gamma _1}, \ldots {\gamma _m}\} ,d(x,{\gamma _i}(x)) \le 2diam(M)$ as in the lemma.Since the number of possible relations  is bounded by ${2^{{m^3}}}$,we have reduced the problem to showing that m is bounded".Why is the number of possible relations  bounded by ${2^{{m^3}}}$,and where does ${2^{{m^3}}}$ come from?The fundamental groups are finitely generated,and the numbers of generators have a uniform upper bound.Does this theorem means that the numbers of the elements of the fundamental groups have a uniform upper bound?(Although it's obviously wrong I think).

Comment: You might want to tag this in differential geometry and/or Riemannian geometry, as well.

Comment: The answer is just at the top of page 277, Lemma 38. It shows that you can always find a presentation of the $\pi_1$ of a Riemannian manifold where all the relations are of the form $\gamma_i\gamma_j=\gamma_k$. Be careful, for a given group, this presentation might feel quite akward (I wonder how to present $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ in this way ?). What theorem 64 on the bottom on the page shows is that there is a bound on the number of generators needed for this presentation, not another one. 

Comment: "all the relations are of the form γiγj=γk"means for any γi,γj,there exists a γk such that γiγj=γk?   

Comment: maybe I should have added that the $\gamma_i$'s are taken from a set of generators.

Comment: I mean we only consider the generator you mentioned,for any γi,γj,there exists a γk such that γiγj=γk? 

Comment: No that's not it. Lemma 38 says that a presentation of the $\pi_1$ is given by $\langle\  \Gamma\|\ R\ \rangle$ where $\Gamma$ is a finite set of generators (the $\gamma_i$'s), and $R$ is a set of relations each of which is of the form $\gamma_i\gamma_j=\gamma_k$ for some triple $(i,j,k)$, but that doesn't mean that you have all the relations corresponding to each triple $(i,j,k)$, you only have some of them.